# How to make Android ListView get refresh automatically?

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh, simplecursortreeadapter

In my app i have a ListView. Data is populated in ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter. I want ListView to be refreshed automatically whenever there is change in database or when i click button. I have tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but its not effective.i couldn,t findout a good solution. I want ListView to be refreshed whenever user enters value in EditText and then press Send Button and save entered data in SQLite database. Here is my Code :

```
public class chatCursor extends Activity {

static MyListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> item_id;
ArrayList<String> item_phone_num;
ArrayList<String> item_msg_body;
ArrayList<String> item_time;
ArrayList<String> item_flag;
ArrayList<String> items;
private Button btn_send;
DbManager manager;
Cursor Cursor;
//ViewHolder holder12;
String contact_for_chat;
String contact_no;
String message_body = "";
Calendar c;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
String time;
EditText et_chat;
String flag;
String msg = "";
ListView lv_chat;
String[] from = new String[]{"Message_body","Time"};
int[] toIDs = new int[]{R.id.msg_body,R.id.time};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    contact_for_chat = bundle.getString("contact_name");
    contact_for_chat = contact_for_chat.replace(" ", "");
    contact_no = Util.getContactNumber(contact_for_chat, chatCursor.this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contact_no, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    manager = new DbManager(this);
    Cursor = manager.Return_SMS(contact_for_chat);

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    time = sdf.format(c.getTime());


    item_id = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
    item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
    item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
    item_time = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
    item_flag = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
    findViews();
    showList();
    //setActionBar();

    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SendSMS();
            showList();
        }
    });

    lv_chat.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int itemId = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(position));

        }});
}

private void showList() {

    showEvents(Cursor);
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_chat, 
            Cursor, 
            from, 
            toIDs);

    lv_chat.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void findViews() {
    et_chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_chat);
    btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    lv_chat = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv_chat.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));

}

protected void SendSMS() {
    SmsManager sms_manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    message_body = et_chat.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms_manager.divideMessage(message_body);
    sms_manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(contact_no, null, parts, null, null);
    flag = "1";
    manager.Insert_sms_data(time, contact_for_chat, message_body,flag);

    if(message_body.length()>0)
    {
        et_chat.setText("");
    }
    showList();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {

    int i=0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        item_id.add(i+"");
        item_time.add(cursor.getString(1));
        item_msg_body.add(cursor.getString(3));
        item_phone_num.add(cursor.getString(2));
        item_flag.add(cursor.getString(4));
        i++;
    }

}
public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    Cursor myCursor;
    Context myContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layout,
            Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        myCursor = c;
        myContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return item_msg_body.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item_msg_body.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return item_msg_body.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View v = arg1;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater layoutinf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.row_chat, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            //  holder.tv_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_num);
            holder.tv_sms_body = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        if(item_flag.get(position).equals("1"))
        {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dateparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dateparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        dateparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.msg_body);

            holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);
            holder.tv_sms_body.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.tv_time.setLayoutParams(dateparams);
        }
        else if(item_flag.get(position).equals("0"))
        {
            holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

        }

        //holder.tv_contact.setText("" + item_phone_num.get(position));
        holder.tv_sms_body.setText(item_msg_body.get(position));
        holder.tv_time.setText(item_time.get(position));

        return v;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {

    private TextView tv_contact;
    private TextView tv_sms_body;
    private TextView tv_time;

}

}
```

Any help will will be appreciated .Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() immediately after calling setAdapter(). Shouldn't you be adding an element before calling this. Because at the instance the adapter is being notified, the lv_chat is already displaying the latest datset.

Comment: where should i use it to let ListView refresh automatically ??

Comment: Before I answer this, let me say that I do not know how you are structuring your app at this time. Having said this, the usual process is to initialize the list view and set the adapter in the onCreate() method itself and then call the notify method when some action has been taken elsewhere. In your case, you have created a custom list adapter with a cursor. The reason you are unable to update is because when the list view is set, it takes the latest result set and hence there is nothing to notify the adapter about at this point. What you need to do is to override the add method (continued...)

Comment: to add only the last result of the cursor to the adapter...  I haven't tried this before but this is the way you have to proceed.

Comment: Infact i am developing SMS app, i have a ListView and at bottom EditText and send button, i want ListView to be updated when i type some text in EditText and press Send button.

Answer (score 0):

call adapter.notifydatasetchanged() method to refresh listview